# why cant my vscode check for C++17 （my compiler is clang 12）？

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang++, vscode-remote

[This follow is my remote server and local vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap1GF.png)

this follow context

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang++-12",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

in my remote c_cpp_properties.json under .vscode folder

settings.json:

```
"C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++17",
    "clang.cxxflags": [
        "-std=c++17"
    ],
```

but my code can be compiled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is because of a cmake tool plugin, find your `compile_commands.json` file in your remote server, and edit to add the option `-std=c++17`; thus, change e.g.

```
"command": "/usr/bin/clang++-12   -g -o CMakeFiles/linuxCode.dir/main.cpp.o -c  /home/source/main.cpp",
```

to

```
"command": "/usr/bin/clang++-12   -g -o CMakeFiles/linuxCode.dir/main.cpp.o -c -std=c++17 /home/source/main.cpp",
```